# Handle undefined methods in Matlab by passing method's name and inputs to a function/method

Tags: matlab, oop, methods

Assume we have a Matlab class called MyClas, as below,

```
classdef MyClass
   properties
      Value
   end
   methods
      function foo(input1, input2)
          ...
      end
   end
end
```

What I am looking for is having `MyClass.anyThing(inputValue)`, where `anyThing` and `inputValue` are arbitrary strings and `anyThing` is not a defined method in `MyClass`, passes `anyThing` and `inputValue` as two strings to my `foo` function.

**In other words**, I want to be able to handle undefined methods by passing their name and inputs to a function/method as strings.

I am having a hard time to elaborate on my issue since I don't know if there is any technical term for what I am trying to pull off here. Yet, I managed to find [this link from math works](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html), which just customizes indexing operations and does not exactly address my issue.

Comment: sounds like dynamically redefining a class... How should that do? A class is a template. But you would only be able to access an instant of a class. Do you now want to upgrade this particular instance or the hole template via the instance where you pass the new method to? In both cases, this was not what is intended with object-oriented programming. I'm afraid that this will never work =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate this by hacking in an implementation of [`subsref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html). Like this:

```
classdef MethodRedirector
    methods
        function varargout = subsref(obj, S)
            if numel(S) == 2 && strcmp(S(1).type, '.') && ...
                    strcmp(S(2).type, '()')
                % Looks like obj.method(args)
                fprintf('In method invocation to: %s with args:\n', S(1).subs);
                celldisp(S(2).subs);
            else
                [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, S);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The restriction is that callers must use the `obj.method(args...)` syntax, and cannot use the (usually equivalent) `method(obj, args...)` syntax.

Here's how that looks in practice:

```
>> mr = MethodRedirector; mr.someMethod(1, '2', magic(3))
In method invocation to: someMethod with args:
ans{1} =
     1
ans{2} =
2
ans{3} =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```